# Asterisk sends SIP bye packet to wrong destination

Tags: asterisk, sip, voip

Asterisk was doing fine, but it failed to send bye packet to caller device recently.

Device B made a SIP call to device A, and device A send a SIP bye packet to device A after 1 minute.

```
Device A - Called Party 
Reg. Contact : sip:2000@211.246.XXX.91:54323 

U 2015/07/13 21:53:44.091979 211.246.XXX.91:54323 -> 10.XXX.72.19:6030
  BYE sip:1000@210.122.11.241:6030 SIP/2.0..Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 102.0.124.254:32580;branch=z9hG4bK.5-5rCW4lT;rport..From: <s
  ip:2000@211.246.XXX.91>;tag=~-IyfmX..To: <sip:1000@210.122.11.241>;tag=as0b8359cf..CSeq: 111 BYE..Call-ID: 04daa
  8b23c0447754405d633412a24bf@210.122.11.241:6030..Max-Forwards: 70..User-Agent: LinphoneAndroid/1.4.11 (belle-sip/1.3.1)....    
#
U 2015/07/13 21:53:44.092354 10.XXX.72.19:6030 -> 211.246.XXX.91:54323
  SIP/2.0 200 OK..Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 102.0.124.254:32580;branch=z9hG4bK.5-5rCW4lT;received=211.246.XXX.91;rport=54323..From: <sip:82
  1092705604@211.246.XXX.91>;tag=~-IyfmX..To: <sip:1000@210.122.11.241>;tag=as0b8359cf..Call-ID: 04daa8b23c0447754405d6334
  12a24bf@210.122.11.241:6030..CSeq: 111 BYE..Server: Asterisk PBX 11.9.0..Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSC
  RIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE..Supported: replaces, timer..Content-Length: 0....


Device B - Caller
Reg. Contact : sip:1000@175.XXX.49.162:9194

U 2015/07/13 21:53:44.127422 10.XXX.72.19:6030 -> 175.XXX.49.162:1439
  BYE sip:1000@175.XXX.49.162:9194 SIP/2.0..Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 210.122.11.241:6030;branch=z9hG4bK3cbc2e04;rport..Max-Forwar
  ds: 70..From: sip:2000@210.122.11.241;tag=as7398fff9..To: <sip:1000@210.122.11.241>;tag=jeOsviSOp..Call-ID: Kki
  zsHTRXS..CSeq: 102 BYE..User-Agent: Asterisk PBX 11.9.0..Proxy-Authorization: Digest username="1000", realm="asterisk",
   algorithm=MD5, uri="sip:210.122.11.241", nonce="23661ac5", response="f286abd0e61b6ca8bde7c3e0aaad0f0d"..X-Asterisk-HangupCause
  : Normal Clearing..X-Asterisk-HangupCauseCode: 16..Content-Length: 0....                                                       
#
U 2015/07/13 21:53:44.627054 10.XXX.72.19:6030 -> 175.XXX.49.162:1439
  BYE sip:1000@175.XXX.49.162:9194 SIP/2.0..Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 210.122.11.241:6030;branch=z9hG4bK3cbc2e04;rport..Max-Forwar
  ds: 70..From: sip:2000@210.122.11.241;tag=as7398fff9..To: <sip:1000@210.122.11.241>;tag=jeOsviSOp..Call-ID: Kki
  zsHTRXS..CSeq: 102 BYE..User-Agent: Asterisk PBX 11.9.0..Proxy-Authorization: Digest username="1000", realm="asterisk",
   algorithm=MD5, uri="sip:210.122.11.241", nonce="23661ac5", response="f286abd0e61b6ca8bde7c3e0aaad0f0d"..X-Asterisk-HangupCause
  : Normal Clearing..X-Asterisk-HangupCauseCode: 16..Content-Length: 0....                                                       
#
U 2015/07/13 21:53:45.627235 10.XXX.72.19:6030 -> 175.XXX.49.162:1439
  BYE sip:1000@175.XXX.49.162:9194 SIP/2.0..Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 210.122.11.241:6030;branch=z9hG4bK3cbc2e04;rport..Max-Forwar
  ds: 70..From: sip:2000@210.122.11.241;tag=as7398fff9..To: <sip:1000@210.122.11.241>;tag=jeOsviSOp..Call-ID: Kki
  zsHTRXS..CSeq: 102 BYE..User-Agent: Asterisk PBX 11.9.0..Proxy-Authorization: Digest username="1000", realm="asterisk",
   algorithm=MD5, uri="sip:210.122.11.241", nonce="23661ac5", response="f286abd0e61b6ca8bde7c3e0aaad0f0d"..X-Asterisk-HangupCause
  : Normal Clearing..X-Asterisk-HangupCauseCode: 16..Content-Length: 0....
```

Asterisk supposed to send bye packet to caller IP address and port number, but port number was different.

Caller IP - 1000@175.XXX.49.162:9194

SIP bye packet destination from server - 100@175.XXX.49.162:1439

Do you see what is the problem?

Comment: 1) SO is not for debug 2) you need check invite packet. most likly it have somewhere address where BYE go.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the Contact in the INVITE message. The REG contact indicate i am available here. Where as the Contact in INVITE means for this session / dialog send all future request to this IP:Port.

Look where the IP:Port being used to send the BYE is and you should be able to figure what it happened like that.